# How to show icon if no row returned

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

How to conditional display a particular icon (for example 'ADD data') only when i have null in column.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
case when name is not null
  then name
  else '<img src="myicon.png"/>'
  end as name
```

You would need to change the column's Display As property to "Standard Report Column" so that this HTML is not escaped by APEX.

If you meant this icon to be a link you can do that the same way:

```
case when name is not null
  then name
  else '<a href="..."><img src="myicon.png"/></a>'
  end as name
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the same icon for every empty cell in any column, you can just add appropriate html-code to attributes settings of your report:

```
Your_Report → Attributes → Show Null Values as → <img src="image.png">
```

Comment: Nice, odd that's never occurred to me before.